How can I remove a stuck screw to replace a Larson storm door hidden closure?
I’ve seen enough posts about Larson Storm Door hidden closures failing to know I got one of the bad batch, and it needs to be replaced— all attempts to adjust the speed of the door slamming have failed, and I’m concerned about the glass breaking.
BUT…I can’t for the life of me get the hex screw on the frame side to release so I can remove the busted hidden closure.
All the screws and the hex on the actual door are coming out, no problem whatsoever, but the one on the frame side is locked up tight. I wonder if I’m missing a release somewhere? It doesn’t feel just over tightened— it feels locked, and I think it’ll snap my Allen wrench before it gives way.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I’ve prowled the internet for a few hours already, and all the instructions boil down to “then just remove the hex screw”, which just isn’t happening at the moment! I’m wondering if I ought to just drill it out.

Welcome. Photos would be a great addition to your post. Please take the [tour].


Whelp, naturally I got it solved right after posting here. Seems like the screw was jammed in crooked, and my technique of “push on it and pull the Allen wrench really hard” finally worked. Leaving this up, though, to help the next person with the misfortune of buying one of these doors!

are you A. Pierce?

Rubber duck effect: explaining your problem to someone else is often surprisingly effective at helping you see you to fix them.
